# File name completion in pry

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

I'm switching `irb` to `pry`. I just found that file name completion in `pry` didn't work.

I have a `foo.rb` in current directory, then I can complete file name like `irb> load 'f[TAB]`, but this completion doesn't work in `pry`.

Is there configuration for this, or it is not possible to use file name completion in `pry`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "shell-mode" or "file-mode (alias for shell-mode)" in pry.